# How do you make a search bar in the body portion of flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a search bar in the bottom of the page like apple maps but all the search bars I have found include using App bar but I'm trying it in the body.

This is my current code:

```dart
body: Center(
  child: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      child: FractionallySizedBox(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        heightFactor: 0.3,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              topRight: Radius.circular(30)),
          child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: Column(children: const <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Welcome to Dituuu!',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
              ])),
        ),
      )),
));
```

[What I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xok5D.png)

This is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: What search bars have you tried?

Comment: I couldnt get any search bars out as all the ones I found online was search bars in the Appbar.

Comment: Just place the TextField where you want, whats the fuss about?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  body: Center(
      child: SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            heightFactor: 0.3,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30)),
              child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Column(children: const <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Welcome to Dituuu!',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 5,),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                      child: TextField(
                        cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            filled: true,
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Search',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontSize: 12
                            ),
                            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ])),
            ),
          )),
    )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).